# Multidimensional Array (Grid Displayed) IF conditions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wan't to display information in a grid view. However when I try to add if conditions to the nested for-loops the format is ruined, why is this? I want a 3x3 grid.

**With IF conditon**

```
    public void tGridPrint()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < page.length; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < page[row].length; column++)

                if(page[row][column] == letter)
                {
                    System.out.print((char)page[row][column] + " ");
                    System.out.println();   
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");
                    System.out.println();
                }

//              System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");
//              System.out.println();

            }

        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
equals1
1 
x 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9
```

**Without IF condition**

```
    public void tGridPrint()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < page.length; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < page[row].length; column++)

//              if(page[row][column] == letter)
//              {
//                  System.out.print((char)page[row][column] + " ");
//                  System.out.println();   
//              }
//              else
//              {
//                  System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");
//                  System.out.println();
//              }

                System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");
                System.out.println();

            }

        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
equals1
1 120 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` should go outside of the inner for loop.  The outer for loop controls the rows and the inner for loop controls the columns.  You're going to a new line after every iteration of the column loop.

Also, not sure if this is incorrect formatting or actually in your code, but the structure should be:

```
for (outer loop)
{
    for (inner loop)
    {
       //...
    }

    System.out.println()
}
```

The brackets are important.  As listed, your second example works, because everything is commented out and the inner for loop is only operating on the `System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");`.  The `System.out.println()` is actually part of the second loop.  Since you have no brackets or code blocks or control-flow statements, the scope of your inner for loop end at the next statement that ends with a semicolon.

Comment: @user2998504 I made an edit.  Not sure if your code is poorly formatted just on SO or not, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You need `System.out.println();` after first loop. Try

```
public void tGridPrint(){
  for (int row = 0; row < page.length; row++){
      for (int column = 0; column < page[row].length; column++){// Add { here
          if(page[row][column] == letter){
              System.out.print((char)page[row][column] + " ");    
           }
           else{
              System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");
             }
           }// First loop.

           System.out.println(); // Use it here 
     }// Second loop.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove  System.out.println() from both if and else block and add after the end of inner for loop... Like this

```
  public void tGridPrint()
    {
    for (int row = 0; row < page.length; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < page[row].length; column++)

            if(page[row][column] == letter)

                System.out.print((char)page[row][column] + " ");

            else

                System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");

     System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to add brackets `{ }` to the if-condition. **this can make the code be more readable and help you to find the issue here.**

Have a try this this:

```
public void tGridPrint()
{

    for (int row = 0; row < page.length; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < page[row].length; column++)
        {
            if(page[row][column] == 'x')
            {
                System.out.print((char)page[row][column] + " ");
               // System.out.println();   
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(page[row][column] + " ");
               // System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

You can get the correct grid display.

```
1 x 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```